# Shallow copy real life usages in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Beyond the regular boring differences for shallow and deep copy differences ,

I was wondering , what are real life scenerios in which i will use shallow copy ?

I dont see any usage ( and i must be wrong about it )

Thanks

Comment: shallow copy is similar to value-type semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example of real-life usage is for providing a sorted list of objects while maintaining a record of original order. Creating shallow copies allows one to provide users with the same list sorted in various ways, but all linking back to original objects.

Comment: But sorting the new list also sort the original list , its the same elements

Comment: It sorts the references to the element. The elements I'm talking about are not value types!

Comment: Pick any ref type (i.e. not a struct) and try something like this
`List<Point3D> original = new List<Point3D>();
original.Add(new Point3D(0, 1, 2));
original.Add(new Point3D(3, 4, 5));
original.Add(new Point3D(6, 7, 8));
original.Add(new Point3D(9, 0, 1));
Point3D[] arr_original = original.ToArray();
Point3D[] arr_copy = (Point3D[])arr_original.Clone(); // shallow copy
Array.Reverse(arr_copy);
if (arr_original[0] != arr_copy[0]) Console.WriteLine("I win!");`

Comment: ouch ... sorry for messy comment! Point is, the original array is left untouched.